# VLC captured clips have no audio

Tags: audio, video, vlc, playback, capture

I can play the .avi file fine in VLC, but when I capture a clip of it, the clip file has no audio.  I don't understand, because it must have the necessary codec to play the audio on the full video, right? But it can't output?

Version 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (Intel 64bit)

thanks